# Alternate to control+drag to connect view element with file owner in xCode interface builder?

Tags: iphone, windows, macos, interface-builder, vnc

Working on an iPhone application through a TightVNC connection into a Mac Mini; the control+drag operation in Interface Builder to connect a view element to file owner doesn't work - I don't see the connecting line.

It does work when I connect keyboard, mouse and monitor to the Mini and work on it directly, however it is a lot more convenient for me to run it through a VNC connection. Must be some quirk of the TightVNC connection that is preventing this.  I tried different TightVNC settings for the cursor (let server handle it and so on) but no luck.

Is there an alternative to control+drag to hook up outlets?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try right-clicking by holding <kbd>Control</kbd> and clicking the element (depending on the keyboard settings, it might be <kbd>Command</kbd> click instead), this will show a popup, and then you can drag the circle on the right hand side of the property you want to link up.

Comment: Dragging views in a storyboard also fails through VNC. Any hint for that?

Comment: I finally figured this out it is clear as mud.  When you have your "View Controller Scene" open, you can right click the "View" you wish to reference which will bring up a bunch of options with circles to the right of them.  One of them will be "New Referencing Outlet".  Click in the circle next to this, and drag it to the view controller.h.  You should then see a blue line with Insert Outlet at the end of it.  Let go and you are on your way...