# How to get control-drag to work for OSX via Windows VNC viewer?

Tags: windows, macos, click, drag, vnc

I'm trying to write an IOS app on my Mac Mini, connecting to it via VNC on a Windows machine.  Tutorials say you should control drag a button from the storyboard to it's corresponding view controller header file to create the button handler.

Control drag does not seem to work via VNC.

What is the work-around for this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725738/alternate-to-controldrag-to-connect-view-element-with-file-owner-in-xcode-inter The answer contains a workaround.